# Change css style based on html element content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Designing room allocation page which contains multiple panel boxes developed in bootstrap.boxes act as an beds.if bed occupied then highlight header as red else green as vacate if clicked on green panel it goes to room allocation page .if clicked on red panel it goes room vacate page so how should i do development any idea using bootstrap and JQuery

```
function myFunc(id){
    if($(id).text()=="")
        $(id).prev().parent().prev().css("background-color","green"); 
    else
        $(id).prev().parent().prev().css("background-color","red"); 
}
```

//i want to call same function on load with mulitiple id passed i am done with onclick event but individually

Comment: Show us what you have worked on yet?

Comment: still i am only implemented boxes with bootstrap panel heading and body

Comment: Please post your code for us to be able to help you. We are not spoon-feeders here.

Comment: i only want to know should i  use panel or button for this type of development anfd effects nashcheez.

Comment: function myFunc(id){
  if($(id).text()=="")
   //window.location.href = "admission.html"; 
       $(id).prev().parent().prev().css("background-color","green"); 
     else
       $(id).prev().parent().prev().css("background-color","red"); 
         //window.location.href = "index.html"; 
}

Comment: This is function written to call the action on click passed value using click event html but i want to call multiple value same function onload is this possible to do then how

Comment: Please write a fiddle and show us what what you got, and then what you want.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=7GKjc9HRJt //this is my  some  jsfiddle code

Comment: i want this data on page load for different id calling same function

Comment: pls share give your jsfiddler link above link not working...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ash3317/mm297223/#&togetherjs=7GKjc9HRJt

Comment: can you please explain me what exactly you want ?? & posted ans of @nashcheez is fullfill your requirement or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a lot of syntax errors and issues with the code.

You can use `jquery.trigger()` to `.roombed` class to trigger the event on load.

Check updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/bzzmq9mw/1/

As far as I could understand your problem, this is what you want:

```js
function myFunc(id) {
  if ($("#" + id).text() == "")
    $("#" + id).parent().css("background-color", "green");
  else
    $("#" + id).parent().css("background-color", "red");
}

$(".roombed").trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="roombedboxB111" style="border:1px solid #FF2D55;width:333px;">
    <div class="roombedhead" style="background-color:green;height:5px;">

    </div>

    <div class="roombed" style="background-color:white;height:116px;" onclick="myFunc('allocatedname1');">
      <label style="margin-left: 100px;">BR-111</label>
      <br />
      <label id="allocatedname1">Jon Doe</label>
      <br />
      <label id="allocatedyear">1st Year</label>
      <br />
      <label id="allocatedyear">Computer</label>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="roombedboxB111" style="border:1px solid #FF2D55;width:333px;">
    <div class="roombedhead" style="background-color:green;height:5px;">

    </div>

    <div class="roombed" style="background-color:white;height:116px;" onclick="myFunc('allocatedname2');">
      <label style="margin-left: 100px;">BR-111</label>
      <br />
      <label id="allocatedname2">Mark Doe</label>
      <br />
      <label id="allocatedyear">1st Year</label>
      <br />
      <label id="allocatedyear">Computer</label>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I already did this i want this function with multiple id call should execute on page load

Comment: Nice! This is what I am trying to implement using onload but  trigger event also good thanks bro!